# Definition of an address space

Tags: virtual-address-space

I'm confused by the "address space" term.
It seems it can be used interchangeably with "memory space".
An example of sentence is: "Loads the specified module into the address space of the calling process"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can address many things.  If the thing that one happens to be addressing is memory, then the address space is indeed the memory space.  A *memory address* denotes a memory word in the memory address space.

But one can address things other than memory.  One can have, to pick just two examples, an *IP version 4 address space*, or an *IP version 6 address space*.  Neither of those is a memory space.  Memory is not addressed in their address spaces; one addresses nodes on a (IP version 4/6) computer network.